# how to run scheduled php background processes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, background

Is it possible to execute a php function according to a timely manner in a web server ?
Ex - execute a function every day at 4.30 PM.

Comment: What control panel is your hosting provider using? Plex, CPanel etc ?

Comment: control panel is a CPanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two methods

**Method 1: Execute the script using php from the crontab**

To execute myscript.php every 1 hour do the following:

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

**Method 2: Run the php script using URL from the crontab**

If your php script can be invoked using an URL, you can lynx, or curl, or wget to setup your crontab as shown below.

The following script executes the php script (every hour) by calling the URL using the lynx text browser. Lynx text browser by default opens a URL in the interactive mode. However, as shown below, the -dump option in lynx command, dumps the output of the URL to the standard output.

```
00 * * * * lynx -dump http://www.domain.com/myscript.php
```

**NOTE: In your case as you wants to RUN CRON at every 4:30 PM then you should do as**

```
30     16    *    *    *
```

Here 30 represents the minutes and 16 represents 4:00 pm of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron jobs for that:

```
30 16 * * * public_html/your_php_file.php
```

That will execute everyday at 4.30pm